# Spring : No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, servlets

I strangely have this problem :

```
[04/07/14 11:31:09:009 CEST]  WARN servlet.PageNotFound: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/datapine-backend/heroku/resources] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'
```

However, I checked the logs and my method is already mapped!

```
   annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/heroku/resources/],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.datapine.heroku.HerokuController.provision(net.sf.json.JSONObject)
```

This my method :

```
@Controller
 public class HerokuController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/heroku/resources/", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> provision(@RequestBody JSONObject body){
        System.out.println("called! \n");
        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put("id", 555);
        response.put("message", "Provision successful!");
      return new ResponseEntity<String>(response.toString(),HttpStatus.OK);     
    }
```

This is my **web.xml**

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/heroku/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is the **rest-servlet.xml** :

```
<beans:import resource="classpath:spring-properties-loader.xml"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.datapine.heroku" />

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>
```

what can be the problem?

thanks.

Comment: could you try to remove trailing slash in you @RequestMapping ?

Comment: Is datapine-backend definitely the context root for your application?

Comment: @white : I am trying; to JamesB : yeah it is datapine-backend that runs on the server

Comment: Your servlet is mapped to `/heroku` leading to a base path of `/datapine-backend/heroku`. Now your controller is mapped to `/heroku/resources/` leading to a path to your controller of `/datapine-backend/heroku/heroku/resources/`. The mappnig of the controller is the mapping inside the dispatcher servlet not inside the application. Either map your servlet to `/` or remove `/heroku` from your `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: @M.Deinum If that is the problem you should definitely add it as an answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum That didn't work..

Comment: Define that in your sentence what have you done that didn't work. Your URL should be mapped fine now, make sure that you do a POSt and not a GET.

Comment: RequestMapping(value = "resources/") and <url-pattern>/heroku/*</url-pattern>. And i am sending a post with "Postman" tool. but still have the no URL mapped. @M.Deinum and this is the request : http://localhost:8080/datapine-backend/heroku/resources

Comment: Remove the trailing '/' on your request mapping.

Comment: @CodeChimp: I did but same error :

Comment: Are you sending it as a POST?

Comment: @CodeChimp yeah i am sending it as a post.

Comment: Are you sending the Accepts as application/json?